# d3js gives typeError "d is undefined"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I built a d3 map and have to access the bound data for various actions. When I do this with `.on("mouseover",...)` or `.on("mousemove",...)`, it works fine. But I want to set the fill color based on these values, too. When I try to do this by `.attr("fill",...)` and a callback function, it gives me a typeError "d is undefinded". Here is a working and a non-working code-example:

```
kommunen
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(featuresKommunen)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "kommune")
    .on("mouseover",function (d){ 

        // gives me the correct values
        console.log(d.properties.AGS) 

    })
```

non-working:

```
kommunen
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(featuresKommunen)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "kommune")
    .attr("fill",function (d){ 

        // gives me TypeError: d is undefined
        console.log(d.properties.AGS)

        // the same here
        console.log(d.properties)

    })
```

Logging the root element instead works again

```
kommunen
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(featuresKommunen)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "kommune")
    .attr("fill",function (d){ 

        console.log(d)
        // works and gives me a list of objects:
        // Object { type: "Feature", properties: Object, geometry: Object }
        // Object { type: "Feature", properties: Object, geometry: Object }
        // Object { type: "Feature", properties: Object, geometry: Object }
        // ...

    })
```

Comment: This code should work, the error has to be somewhere else. Can you set up a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, found it. My geojson seems to have some objects without properties. If I check existence with an if-statement before the code is executed it works.

Comment: If you feel like there is something to learn for the rest of us, please write self-answer. If it is just a simple one-time data irregularity of your special setup you might want to consider deleting this question altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My geojson produced some objects without properties and coordinates (wherever they came from...) so that they were not visible on the screen but exited in the DOM. After I wrote a small statement to check if properites are defined, it worked!

```
kommunen
.selectAll("path")
.data(featuresKommunen)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("class", "kommune")
.attr("fill",function (d){

   // works by skipping the missing properies-values
   if (d.properties) {console.log(d.properties.AGS)}

})
```